# how to rebuild targets when scons command is changed in command builder?

Tags: scons

I am trying to use `env.command(command)`.
I am trying to use command builder in my sconscript. This command is not working when i do incremental builds.

when i first compiled, it had compiled the targets or executed the command.
I tried by changing the command and recompiled. Though there is change in command, its not recompiling the target. How to rebuild targets when the command line changed?

Is this possible?

Comment: The actuall call signiture of Command is "env.Command(target, source, action, [key=val, ...])
"  can you provide a small example where you're not seeing rebuilds when the command changes? (I'm assuming you actually mean the specified action in the call to env.Command(...))

Comment: Note it should be recompiling if you change the sources, targets, or the command's action.